# Returning ResponseEntity with info

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm kind of new with Spring. I have made following method:

```
public ResponseEntity<Borders> updateBorder(@Valid @RequestBody Borders borders) throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to update Borders : {}", borders);
    Boolean ok = deviceService.updateBorder(borders);
    return new ResponseEntity(ok ? HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

My method is now returning `ResponseEntity` with `HttpStatus.CREATED` or `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST`. When implementing frontEnd to my software I was wondering it would be very handy, if method could also return a `String` with HttpStatus. Like "Border is updated!" or "Border could not be updated because... pla pla".

What would be best way to return something more specific also to front-end?

Answer (score 1):

you can return something like this , but your method return type should be ResponseEntity < String >, and if you want you pass headers as well.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

```
return new ResponseEntity("your message", ok ? HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Comment: It should be better if he had the method return type to `ResponseEntity<?>`. In this way the software will be more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

ResponseEntity allows to return three types of data:

1. HTTP Status code
2. Body
3. HTTP Header

For each combination of this data you will find a matching constructor. What you are looking for is the body which is an arbitrary object containing the data to be returned. Depending on the Accept header of your request the body will be returned in the requested data format, e.g. application/json. You can even return a simple String as body:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> updateBorder(@Valid @RequestBody Borders borders) throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to update Borders : {}", borders);
    Boolean ok = deviceService.updateBorder(borders);
    return new ResponseEntity("Border could not be updated", ok ? HttpStatus.CREATED : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Then return type cannot be ResponseEntity<Borders>

Comment: I've changed it to String for the correctness of this example. Alternatively, you could also use type Borders as body.